# 3D animated movie about a boy who ventures through a portal to a world populated by large aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, animation

I remember watching a 3D animated movie more than seven years ago ago.

It was about a boy or a young man who has a companion or pet of some kind (I think it was a robot maybe?) who goes into a portal that leads to an alien planet for some reason. I think it had something to do with his father. He ends up on a world with aliens much larger than him.

At one point, he is at a feast or something of the sort and is served a giant brain, to which he replies with something along the lines of "I'm allergic to anything above the neck... ears, tongues, and that includes brains", and that's all I can remember of that movie.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and what did the boy look like (hair colour, style, etc)...?

Comment: @LogicDictates I don't remember. All I can say for certain is that it was more than even years ago. Just how long ago, I don't remember. I don't have any recollection of his appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is ***[Thru the Moebius Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thru_the_Moebius_Strip)*** (2005).

> *Thru the Moebius Strip* (Chinese: 魔比斯环; pinyin: móbǐsī huán) is a Hong Kong–produced 3D-CGI feature film, made in mainland China.

> The story is about the coming of age of a 14-year-old boy who grew up refusing to accept the loss of his father. He reaches the planet Raphicca 27.2 million light years away to find that his father is a prisoner in a kingdom of giant aliens who believe in magic and a medieval code of chivalry. In the midst of a raging battle between good and evil, Jac rescues his father, his new-found family of aliens, the planet of Raphicca, and ultimately, the universe.

The whole film is up on YouTube, but the scene with the brain occurs at [about 43 minutes into the runtime](https://youtu.be/x6aRowPnMXk?t=2589):

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the film I was remembering.